# Why this 2 WAN IPs are different (SIM card router)

Tags: networking, router, ip

I'm aware that routers have 2 IPs, but the public IP on my router is **10.XX.XX.X** and the one from whatismyip, is **15X.XXX.XX.X**. This is a SIM card router.

It may be that the router is itself on a network, and the IP of the router is local to that network. But they call it WAN IP on the config, so I'm confused.

Any ideas? Router is Huawei hardware name *B618s-22d*

Comment: 10.x.x.x is not a public IP. You are probably behind CGNAT. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you, found out a helpful picture here https://ipwithease.com/public-ip-vs-private-ip/ for the ip thing